# EmberRoute.controller returning undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am running ember 1.6.0. [The docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_controller) say that since 1.6.0 there has been a property on Ember Route objects which contains the controller defined for that route. How ever when I call that property, I get undefined.

```
App.PhotosRoute = App.LibraryRoute.extend({
  model: function () {
    //blah
  },

  afterModel: function () {
    this.controller     // => undefined
    var _this = this

    App.store.find('batch').then(function (batches) {
      if (batches.content.length) {
        //unrelated note: _this returns "ReferenceError: _this is not defined" here which really confuses me
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Obviously i could do something terrible like App.**container**.lookup to get the controller here but I'm really wondering why I can't just call the controller property.

My two guesses: 
  a) this property is set at some point afterModel runs
  b) the fact that my route inherits from a route other than EmberRoute is causing some problem

Also, as an aside, if anyone could school me up on some javascript basics as to why the variable "_this" I'm defining is not available in the context of my promise return it would also be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`afterModel` is called before `setupController`, so the controller is not set yet, perhaps move your code there, remember to call `this._super(model, controller);`.

And as always with ember use the getters and setters.

Comment: the docs use this example: 
    if (this.controller.get('userHasEnteredData')

so I would assume you shouldn't need the get in this case unless I am missing some difference in the context

Comment: @Andrew I noticed something else, see answer

Comment: This ended up being correct. Based on [this list](http://blog.trackets.com/2013/02/08/router-request-lifecycle.html) I found that renderTemplate is the first router hook to run after setupController. By moving this logic into renderTemplate, I can now call this.controller

Any idea on why I'm losing the "_this" variable inside my promise return?

Comment: The missing variable was actually just a result of a bug in the ember debugger when dealing with promise returns. The variable is in fact in context there.